# Simulating text-align center for selected option in a select using simple javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select, drop-down-menu

I'm wondering if its possible to 'simulate' a text-align: center; for a select (**with cross browser compatibility**) by using a parent container and a simple javascript (or jQuery) script. I would like to do it without having to install a js library, hence the desire for a simple script.

Objective: make the text centered relative to the outer (dotted) container when either option is selected, regardless of screen width. I only want this for the selected value (i.e. the effective placeholder), I am not worried about the format of the option dropdowns.

**This needs a javascript answer - cannot be done purely in CSS**

https://jsfiddle.net/zs0or8et/1/

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Longtextoption</option>
    <option>Short</option>
  </select>
</div>

<style>

div {
  width:100%;
  outline: 1px dotted;
}

select {
  margin-left:50%;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  background:none; 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
/* BELOW TRANSLATION NEEDS TO BE MADE DYNAMIC DEPENDING ON WIDTH OF SELECTED OPTION */
  transform: translate(-50px);
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you feel about using another div to hold your value?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <select onchange="change(this)">
    <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
    <option value="0">Scotty Auten</option>
    <option value="1">Adriane Gaillard</option>
    <option value="2">Tequila Goodnough</option>
  </select>
  <div id="value" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">Please Select</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
select {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  color: white;
  text-color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
option {
  color: black;
  text-color: black;
}
```

JS

```
function change(item) {
  var name = item.options[item.selectedIndex].text
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = name;
}
```

We use aria hiding to hide the value div from a screen reader.

Comment: This appears to work well across browsers and on mobile. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding the `text-align` property to the parent div as below, also your `select` style class

```css
div {
  width:100%;
  outline: 1px dotted;
}

select {
  margin-left:50%;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  background:none; 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
/* BELOW TRANSLATION NEEDS TO BE MADE DYNAMIC DEPENDING ON WIDTH OF SELECTED OPTION */
  transform: translate(-50px);
  /* Align content styles below */
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  text-align-last: -webkit-center;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Longtextoption</option>
    <option>Short</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Needs to be cross-browser compatible

Comment: I've edited the answer to support Safari, by using `-webkit-center;` instead of just center, can you try this?

Comment: Doesn't fix it. Needs a javascript solution

Comment: Well, if it has to be a javascript solution then you can use JS to assign the text-align style to the content of the select tag

Comment: Except this doesn't fix it because it is effectively doing the same as CSS

Comment: Need to dynamically take the width of the selected item and offset it using translate.